# Is it a bad practice to have nested forms?

Tags: html

Is it a bad practice to have something like this?:

```
<form method="post">

<form method="post">
</form>

</form>
```

Comment: 100% bad....never use nested forms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Very much so. And it won't work properly. I would restructure the page to make sure it doesn't have it nested..

Answer (score 1):

It is completely invalid markup - it will break in various painful, interesting and different ways in various browsers. Is it bad practice to write invalid HTML? (hint: yes, it's a Bad Idea) Even if you don't give a rat's ass about valid HTML, is it bad practice to write HTML which is almost certain to give your users incorrect behavior? (hint: yes, it's a Bad Idea, unless you passionately hate your users)

Comment: I hate my users and I *still* wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that will never work as expected properly. 100% bad practice as far as I know / am concerned.